# How to remove n from an array without mutating it?

Tags: javascript

Hi this question needed to be deleted

Comment: use `filter` . but what you have tried so far ?

Comment: `Array.filter()` creates a new array with all the elements removed that return false on the filter function. Removing an item inside the array, by mutating it, can be done with `Array.splice()`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I remove a particular element from an array in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5767325/how-do-i-remove-a-particular-element-from-an-array-in-javascript)

Comment: @SimoV8, that question isn't about immutable changes

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You could use `filter` or `reduce`, or copy the array first by using `slice`, and then perform `splice`.

Personally, I like `filter` for its simplicity, and clear intention

#### filter

```js
function removeItem(array, n) {
  return array.filter((elem, i) => i !== n);
}

const original = [1,2,3,4];

console.log(removeItem(original, 1));
console.log(original);
```

#### reduce

```js
function removeItem (array, n) {
  return array.reduce((result, elem, i) => {
    if (i !== n) result.push(elem);
    return result;
  }, [])
}

const original = [1,2,3,4];

console.log(removeItem(original, 1));
console.log(original);
```

#### slice and splice

```js
function removeItem(array, n) {
  const result = array.slice();
  result.splice(n, 1);
  return result;
}

const original = [1,2,3,4];

console.log(removeItem(original, 1));
console.log(original);
```

#### Performance Test

https://jsperf.com/so53833297

#### Documentation

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice

Answer (score 2):

```
function removeItem(array, n) {
    return array.filter((x, i) => i != n)
}
```